# Why does Intellij not recognise my pom file

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ does not recognise my pom file, it says 'cannot resolve symbol' for every element and marks them red ?
- however the pom file builds fine ?

Ive tried re-importing with no effect.

(Note that the icon for the pom file is not the usual m symbol ? )
[image]

Comment: What's your version of IDE? OS?

Comment: add it as a module or remove it from ignored poms

Comment: Version is intelliJ ultimate 201.3.4  Build #IU-183.5429.30